Best strategy to determine which of two coins is biased using only two flips
We have two coins - one fair, and one biased with a probability of 0.6 for flipping a head. We get to make exactly two flips before making a guess as to which coin is biased. The question is which strategy gives us a higher probability of being able to determine the biased coin - flipping each coin once, or any one coin twice?
Using simple probability rules and Bayes' Theorem, I determined the following probabilities, though I'm not sure how to proceed from here to determine the best strategy.
Case I: We flip any one coin twice
$$\mathrm P(Biased\ Coin\ |\ HH) \approx 0.59$$
$$\mathrm P(Biased\ Coin\ |\ TT) \approx 0.39$$
$$\mathrm P(Biased\ Coin\ |\ TH) \approx 0.49$$
$$\mathrm P(Biased\ Coin\ |\ HT) \approx 0.49$$
Case II: We flip both coins once each
For the outcomes HH and TT, we get no new information about the coin and the probability of either of the two being biased given those outcomes is still 0.5.
$$\mathrm P(First\ Coin\ Biased\ |\ HT) = P(Second\ Coin\ Biased\ |\ TH) = 0.6$$
$$\mathrm P(First\ Coin\ Biased\ |\ TH) = P(Second\ Coin\ Biased\ |\ HT) = 0.4$$
How do we decide which is a better strategy to guess the biased coin correctly? Is one even better than the other? And do we need the probabilities I've calculated for determining the same?

Once you have written out the strategy, just look at all possible paths (along with their probabilities). That will give you the total probability that your strategy works.  For this problem, I'd say that the strategy with the highest total probability of success is the winner (other metrics are possible, of course, but I bet this is the one they want).

Should say:  your numbers seem off.  For case (ii), you are claiming that, in the $HT$ case, there is a $70%$  chance that the second coin is biased?  Why would that be?  Surely seeing $HT$ is at least some evidence that the first coin is biased.  Also, keep in mind that the sum of all probabilities attached to a fixed condition must be $1$.

Thanks for pointing that out! I've corrected the numbers now.

Without loss of generality, assume that the fair coin is Coin-1 and that the biased Coin is Coin-2.
Further, assume that in the Case 1 option of flipping a coin twice, your strategy will be:

If 0 Heads, guess that the coin being flipped is Coin-1.
If 1 Heads, $~(1/2)~$ the time guess that the coin being flipped is  Coin-1 and $~(1/2)~$ the time guess that the coin being flipped is Coin-2.
If 2 Heads, guess that the coin being flipped is Coin-2.

Further, assume that in the Case 2 option of flipping both coins once, your strategy will be:

If different number of Heads on the two coins, guess that coin with higher number of Heads is Coin-2.
If both coins show same number of Heads, then $~(1/2)~$ the time guess that the first coin flipped is Coin-2 and $~(1/2)~$ the time guess that the 2nd coin flipped is Coin-2.

So, the question is: under these strategies, which Case is more likely to yield the accurate identification of Coin-2, using the Case-1 approach or using the Case-2 approach?

Case 1 approach:
$~(1/2)~$ the time, you will be flipping Coin-1, without knowing it. 
When that happens:

$(1/4)~$ of the time, your guess will be correct, because the fair coin showed  $~2~$ tails.

$(1/2)~$ of the time, the coin will show 1 Heads and 1 Tails (in some order).  
In that event, your guess will (itself) be correct (1/2) the time, 
because of your strategy here of guessing that the coin is Coin-1 $~50\%~$ of the time, and guessing that the coin is Coin-2 $~50\%~$ of the time.

$(1/4)~$ of the time, your guess will be wrong, because the fair coin showed two Heads.


So, the partial total of a successful identification of Coin-2, that relates to the coin flipped being Coin-1 is:
$$(1/2) \times [ ~(1/4) + (1/4) ~] = (1/4) = (0.25).$$
$~(1/2)~$ the time, you will be flipping Coin-2, without knowing it. 
When that happens:

$(0.16)~$ of the time, your guess will be wrong, because the biased coin showed  $~2~$ tails.

$(0.48)~$ of the time, the coin will show 1 Heads and 1 Tails (in some order).  
In that event, your guess will (itself) be correct (1/2) the time, 
because of your strategy here of guessing that the coin is Coin-1 $~50\%~$ of the time, and guessing that the coin is Coin-2 $~50\%~$ of the time.

$(0.36)~$ of the time, your guess will be correct, because the biased coin showed two Heads.


So, the partial total of a successful identification of Coin-2, that relates to the coin flipped being Coin-2 is:
$$(1/2) \times [ ~(0.24) + (0.36) ~] = (0.30).$$
So, the chance of a successful identication, within Case 1 is
$$(0.25) + (0.30) = (0.55).$$

Case 2 approach:

Coin-1 and Coin-2 show same number of Heads: 
Probability of this occurring is
$(0.5 \times 0.6) + (0.5 \times 0.4) = 0.5$ 
Result = probability of accurate identification is $~0.5.$ 
This is because of the strategy that when both coins show the same number of Heads, $~50\%~$ of the time you will guess that the first coin flipped is Coin-2, and $~50\%~$ of the time you will guess that the second coin flipped is Coin-2.

Coin-1 shows Tails and Coin-2 shows Heads.
Probability of this occurring is $~(0.5 \times 0.6) = 0.3.$
Result = probability of accurate identification is $~1.0.$ 
That is, since the biased coin is the one that showed Heads, your guess will be correct.

Coin-1 shows Heads and Coin-2 shows Tails.
Probability of this occurring is $~(0.5 \times 0.4) = 0.2.$
Result = probability of accurate identification is $~0.0.$ 
That is, since the fair coin is the one that showed Heads, your guess will be wrong.


So, total probability of guessing correctly equals
$$(0.5 \times 0.5) + (0.3 \times 1) = 0.55.$$

$\underline{\text{Conclusion}}$
The Case-1 approach and Case-2 approach are equally effective.
